# Ошибка при установке sentry-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer, sentry

Делаю по гайду с документации https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/

Прописываю composer require sentry/sentry-laravel
Успешно устанавливаю
Далее нужно настроить DSN, прописываю "php artisan sentry:publish --dsn=https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0", как в гайде.

И во время запуска теста получаю следующее
DSN discovered from Laravel config or `.env` file!
Sending test event...
There was an error sending the event.
Please check if your DSN is set properly in your `.env` as `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` or in your config file `config/sentry.php`.

Не могу понять в чем дело, что не так с DSN, как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

В общем как я и думал, вот в этом месте "https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0" тут нужен свой уникальный ключ, который дадут при регистрации.

Так что чтобы решить ошибку нужно зарегистрировать и получить свой уникальный DSN.